# Code doesn't work without .show() - jQuery

Tags: jquery, show

```
    this.randomtip = function(){
        var length = $("#showcase ul li").length;
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
        $("#showcase ul li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
    };
    randomtip();
```

..the code above works well with `.show()` in the end, but if I change it to `.addClass('show')` it won't work.

I'd like to give it a class instead to apply `float:left` property to all `li` items instead of the default `display:list-item`. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Any feedback to my comment? Please make clearer what you are actually trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Jordan's answer:

You can replace the `display:none` from `li` and then add the class this way:

```
$("#showcase ul li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").css('display','').addClass('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you hiding the element in the first place? If you're setting it to `display: none`, for example, or using jQuery's hide(), which does the same thing, then that will override CSS defined elsewhere and keep your element hidden until you remove it. It ought to work if you use both `.show()` (to remove `display: none`) and `.addClass('show')` (to add your CSS class).

Comment: I'm using display:none on LI's, yes. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$("#showcase ul li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
```

with this one

```
$("#showcase ul li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").addClass('show').show();
```

Comment: That almost solves the problem, technically, but the other li's are still hidden. I'd like this code to show atleast 7 li's every rotation, what do I change in the code? Thanks!

Comment: Huh? To be honest I don't have the feeling your comment relates to the question you asked or the information you provided in there. What do you mean with "every rotation" and "atleast 7 li's". Please elaborate the question on what you really are trying to achive. What your code at the moment does is show 1 random `li` according to your selector

Answer (score 0):

instead of `display: none`, use `.addClass('hidden')` / `.removeClass('hidden')`